# Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init -- Ubuntu server 8.04LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xen

I recently copied the logical volume containing an Ubuntu Server install from one Xen server to another.  I have done this many times in the past and have not had issues before.  However, when I attempt to boot my virtual server I get the following error:

```
mount: Mounting /root/dev on /dev/.static/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: Mounting /sys /root/sys failed: Invalid argument
mount: Mounting /proc /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init
```

Several of the possible fixes involve booting with a live CD, which I have downloaded twice now both times getting the following error:

```
BusyBox v1.15.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.3-1ubunty5) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

{initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: Input/output error
Can no mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.sqyashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

I am trying to avoid having to re build this entire server so I am hoping I can figure something out.  Any thoughts on what might be causing my issues or better ways to migrate the virtual machine would be helpful.

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: How did you copy the volume over?  dd?

Comment: something might have messed up on the dump/restore.  Your looking at more work, not doing it again.